# Editing contact form's required field does not work

Tags: magento-1.9, contact-form

My client wants to have the comment in conatct form as optional. I changed the below code but then form does not work any more "Unable to submit your request. Please, try again later"!

```
<li class="wide">
     <label for="comment" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
     <div class="input-box">
           <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment')) ?>" class="required-entry input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
     </div>
</li>
```

to

```
<li class="wide">
    <label for="comment" ><?php echo Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
         <textarea name="comment" id="comment" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape(Mage::helper('contacts')->__('Comment')) ?>" class="input-text" cols="5" rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was removing below from IndexController.php :)

```
if (!Zend_Validate::is(trim($post['comment']) , 'NotEmpty')) {
                        $error = true;
                    }
```